# How to display an image using c?

Tags: c, image

I want to display an image using c in linux platform.And now i have read the image file ( gif)into an array of char. But I don't know what to do next to display it? Can anybody help me?

Comment: Install [AA-lib](http://aa-project.sourceforge.net/index.html) and have fun :)

Answer (score 4):

This is a quite complicated question since you're not being very specific.

C in itself doesn't have a concept of an "image" or even a "display". You need to mix in some environment-specific details that add such concepts, for instance you could work with the Framebuffer in (console) Linux, the X11 window environment, GNOME/GTK+, KDE or perhaps Enlightenment.

All of these give radically different answers.

Answer (score 3):

You need a graphic toolkit to do that. Plain old **C language** is not enough.

You can try these toolkits:

1. QT
2. GTK

There are many others that will also do what you want, but these two are among the most populars I guess.